# Using variable from onComplete() method while working with Firestore database

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a collection in Cloud Firestore and I need to store the informations from database in a list (coordPlaces). I did it like this, created these methods:

```
private void readData(FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback){
    db.collection("AddPlaces")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        if(task.getResult() != null){
                            List<ListPlacesModel> list = task.getResult().toObjects(ListPlacesModel.class);
                            for(ListPlacesModel model : list)
                            {
                                LatLng place = new LatLng(model.getPlaceLat(), model.getPlaceLng());
                                coordPlaces.add(place);
                                String name = model.getPlaceName();
                                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(place).title(name));
                            }
                            firestoreCallback.onCallback(coordPlaces);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("ERROR", String.valueOf(task.getException()));
                    }
                }
            });
}

private interface FirestoreCallback{
        void onCallback(List<LatLng> myList);
    }
```

And then called the method like this:

```
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        readData(new FirestoreCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(List<LatLng> myList) {  
        });
```

I've saw this solution in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ofkvm97i0s&ab_channel=AlexMamo).

But now I need to access this list in order to creathe a 2D array out of it, in this manner:

```
for(int i=0;i<coordPlaces.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<coordPlaces.size();j++)
    {
      int distance = (int) SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(coordPlaces.get(i), coordPlaces.get(i+1));
      graph[i][j] = distance;
    }
}
```

Anywhere in the code where I put these 2 for loops, my app crashes. I can't find a solution of how to create this 2D array.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only places where you should add those lines of code should be either inside `onComplete()` or if you're using a custom callback inside `onCallback()`. If you place those lines in any other parts of your class, you'll get an empty list, hence that IndexOutOfBoundsException.

If you don't want to use that approach, you might also consider using a [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) object, as it's a type of object that can be observed. If you understand Kotlin, the following resource will help:

- [How to read data from Cloud Firestore using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953)

Comment: I'm using Java.
Also, I can put these lines inside readData onCallback(), inside onComplete or inside FirestoreCallback onCallback and my app crashes.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Hey Oana. Have you solved the issue?

Comment: Not yet, I can't understand what my logcat is telling me. I try to do this operations in a MapsActivity and when I put the for loop anywhere, my map shows for one sec and then it crash and send me back to the previous activity.

Comment: I did a test now. The errors from logcat are some errors that appear from when I start the app. There is no error in logcat when my MapActivity crashes.

Comment: Without seeing the entire stack trace and the **exact** code that produces that error, I cannot be much of a help. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Also, I tried to make a public static void distanceCalc(List<LatLng> list) and inside I put the for loop + a for loop to print the content of graph[][]. If I call this method inside theprivate interface Firestorecallback onCallback method, my MapsActivity don't crush, but it prints absolutely nothing

Comment: So can I help you with other any information regarding the initial issue?